# Running AjaxControlToolkit Sanitizer On Escaped text

Tags: json, rss, json.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

My scenario is that I'm reading in RSS (which is XML), serializing it to JSON via Json.net, running the AjaxControlToolkit Sanitizer on the JSON, before finally serializing the JSON to a c# class (so I can pull out the text of each item in the RSS feed).

The problem I'm encountering is that HTML attribute quotes in the content of each item are being (properly I think) escaped when the feed is serialized from XML to JSON. But the sanitizer takes that escaped quote and then further escapes it into hex. So 
    <a href=\"www.foo.com\">foo</a> becomes <a href="&#x5C;&#x26;quot&#x3B;www.foo.com&#x26;quot&#x3B;">.

In other words, horribly mangled. :-) This now unescaped quote in the JSON after sanitization is blowing up JSON.net.

I need two things, first to run the sanitizer on the feed item content (to satisfy my information security department), and second to serialize the JSON to C# so I can easily pull the content out. Any ideas?

Comment: Would something like https://superfeedr.com help? We convert RSS/Atom into a JSON pretty cleanly.

Comment: In case someone comes by looking for this, the solution was to not run the Sanitizer on the entire JSON. Instead I'm running the sanitizer on the HTML of the item body when it's getting used. So the unsanitized HTML is still stored in the system, but at least it gets cleaned before it's used.